# ExtJS Models and Associations

Tags: model, refactoring, extjs4.2, model-associations

In the past few days I've been stuck with a problem related to the Data package and I can't find a way around it!

My project: Task Assignment App (simple enough :P)

GitHub: https://github.com/prototyp3/task-assignments.git (extjs 4.2.1 not included)

At first I was following a tutorial that had every model in the same file (app.js) but now I've decided to have each one of my models in their respective file but I can't seem to get it to work with the **belongsTo** association. The only difference, besides the multiple files, was the class names that now reflect the package - 'Tasks.model.User' instead of 'User'.

My problem revolves around this. I know it works because I was able to finish the tutorial, but now I can't seem to find any example that applies to my project structure and no matter what I try can't use the getter/setter (getUser() or getTask() from each the assignment).

NOTE: My first problem when I starter this refactoring was the **hasMany** association but I've already found how to handle this (using the "name: 'assignments'").

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but no! I quit trying to fight ExtJS and put all my models in one single file.

Comment: you just need to follow the right naming convention :) are you still using the same code from the github repo?

Comment: No, I'm not! In fact I removed it :( (I didn't remember why it was there, until now)

Comment: Could you give a simple example (or point to documentation on that subject) in the form of an answer just for future reference.

Comment: I will add an answer in the next few days